# strange behavior of autocomplete textsearch when inputting "_" or multiple "_"

Tags: jquery, search

I have this function for textsearch:

```
public function getData()
    {
        $term = Input::get('term');

            /**  check if any matches found in the database table */

            $data = DB::table('items')->distinct()->select('item_name')->where('item_name', 'LIKE', $term . '%')->groupBy('item_name')->take(15)->get();
            foreach ($data as $v) {
                $return_array[] = array('value' => strtolower($v->item_name));
            }


            if (isset ($return_array)) {
                return Response::json($return_array);
            }

    }
```

I don't have any data containing the symbol "_" (underscore) in my DB yet if I input _ or multiple _ (__ ____ _____) I get results showing in the input field based on number of words, example ___ will show items with 3 characters names, ____ items with 4 characters name and so on. How possible? Any clue?

Comment: `_ ` is a one word character match in SQL `LIKE _`

Comment: you mean SQL will match any 3 character words if inputting ___ for example?

Comment: ok I found that out, what about preventing that behaviour?

Comment: escape wildcard characters using appropriate functions